# Recursive linked list from array

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

I am working through the examples in Eloquent Javascript and I cannot seem to generate a working solution to recursively go from an array to a linked list.

The first (iterative) approach seems to work. I am stumped by the recursion. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
    var retObj = {};
    var current = retObj;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        current.value = arr[i];
        if (arr[i + 1] === undefined) {
            current.rest = null;
        } else {
            current.rest = {};
        }
        current = current.rest;
    }
    return retObj;
}

function recArrayToList(arr, obj) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return 'DONE!';
    }
    obj.value = arr[0];
    obj.rest = {};
    return recArrayToList(arr.slice(1), obj.rest);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"linked list"*? A sample of input and expected results always helps

Comment: I don't think you want to return the string 'DONE!', have you tried returning `obj`?

Comment: @charlietfl: Fairly standard [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)...?

Comment: @IrkenInvader: returning `obj` gives an empty object. @charleitfl: `console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}`(taken from Eloquent Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

In this example we're building the current item by setting its value to be the first item in the array and the rest we'll set to the result of the recursive call. The stop condition sets the `rest` to `null` (meaning - we're done:

```js
    function recArrayToList(arr) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            return null; // last element
        }
        var obj = {};
        obj.value = arr[0];          
        obj.rest = recArrayToList(arr.slice(1)); // recursive call
        return obj;
    }

    // example
    console.log(recArrayToList([1,2,3]));
```

The code in the question was close, but there are two mistakes:

1. it didn't handle the stop condition properly
2. the recursive call didn't set `obj.rest` the way it should have

Comment: This answer was very helpful, thank you @alfasin. Preserved the original structure and helped me see my errors.

Comment: Instead of returning null, it should return `obj.rest = null`

Comment: @JosanIracheta how do you return an assignment ?

Comment: @alfasin `return obj.rest = null` assigns the value to `obj.rest` and then returns from the function. That way the last `rest` will have the value of `null`

Comment: @JosanIracheta but you don't have a handle to the object that was created in the previous recursive call... Try to implement your suggestion and let me know ;)

Comment: @R.Long if this answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the checkbox on its left

Comment: @JosanIracheta you *do* understand that `return obj.rest = null` has the same affect as `return null` right ? the assignment has a return value of `null` so when you "return" an assignment you're practically returning a `null` which is assigned (again) to `obj.rest` in the line: `obj.rest = arrayToList(array.slice(1))`

Comment: @alfasin you seemed so certain that this way wouldn't work in your previous comment lol however, thanks for pointing out that they perform the same function in this case

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a single-linked list (meaning it only goes one way), you'll also need to pass in the root as well. You could have this be a default parameter that you don't need to pass in the first time.

Similarly, you can also make `obj` an optional parameter which will self-initialize as well, making your initial call just `recArrayToList(someArr)`.

```js
function recArrayToList(arr, obj, root) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            obj.rest = null;
            return root;
        }
        
        if (!obj) {
          obj = {};
        }

        if (!root) {
          root = obj;
        }

        obj.value = arr[0];
        obj.rest = {};
        return recArrayToList(arr.slice(1), obj.rest, root);
    }
    
let current = recArrayToList([1,2,3,4,5]);

while(current.rest) {
  console.log(current.value);
  current = current.rest;
}
```

You can also crunch it down a bit with some more compact JS (some people don't like some of these conventions):

```js
function recArrayToList(arr, obj, root) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            obj.rest = null;
            return root;
        }
        
        obj = obj || {};
        root = root || obj;
        Object.assign(obj, { value: arr.shift(), rest: {} });
        return recArrayToList(arr, obj.rest, root);
    }
    
let current = recArrayToList([1,2,3,4,5]);

while(current.rest) {
  console.log(current.value);
  current = current.rest;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the result of this function would always be an empty object - the last empty node.

Comment: Did you try to run it ?

Comment: Only in my head. However, it makes sense that if what's returned is the result of `recArrayToList`, and the only return value is `obj`, and when that happens it's an empty object, then that's what you'll get.

Comment: Indeed it would. My mistake. Updated my answer with a functioning example. =p

Comment: I took the liberty to improve it a bit :) That's a good solution but there is one slight change from the requirements: in the OP's iterative approach the last element has `rest` point to `null` while in this solution the last element's `rest` points to `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit which removed your edit, but I think I put your change back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function recArrayToList(arr, current, retObj) {
  var obj = current;

   if(retObj){
      obj = retObj;
   }

   if (arr.length === 0) {
      return current;
   }

   obj.value = arr[0];
   obj.rest = {};

   return recArrayToList(arr.slice(1), current, obj.rest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function recArrayToList(arr) {
  if(arr.length === 0){
    return null;
  }
  return {value: arr[0], rest: recArrayToList(arr.slice(1))}; 
}

console.log(recArrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive version has some flaws. "Done!" is not really what you want as return value if you expect a linked list.

It is also nicer if you don't have to pass the result object as second argument, as the recursive call should really not have to know the object its value is going to be used in. You can do it without that.

It helps to think that the recursive call returns the `rest` value, and that you can inject that immediately in that property as you create the wrapper object as an object literal. And then you find that the code really reduces to just one return statement... which you can combine with the stop condition in a ternary operator:

```js
function recArrayToList(arr) {
    return arr.length ? {
        value: arr[0],
        rest: recArrayToList(arr.slice(1))
    } : null;
}

const list = recArrayToList([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(list);
```